# Implement pager for views in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, pagination, drupal-views

i am new to Drupal. I have to implement a pager in Drupal-7 for views. I have read 
`themer_pager_next() and theme_pager_previous()` 
but i am not able to use these functions. Please tell me how can i use these functions. I have to implement `<< Next || Prev >>` pager. And please tell me in which file i have to implement my paging function.

Comment: views have pager options, no need to write your own. You want to theme "Next" & "Prev" ?

Comment: yes i have to implement << Next || Previous >> pager

Answer (score 3):

this is the markup of a pager in views

```
<div class="item-list">
    <ul class="pager">
    <li class="pager-previous first">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="pager-current">1 of 4</li>
    <li class="pager-next last"><a href="url">››</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

you can either add css to style.css of your theme
or with theme_* functions , check the links below

- [D7 override theme pager](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9825/in-drupal-7-how-to-override-theme-pager)
- [Customize views pager in D7](http://www.cyber-sundae.com/create-custom-pager-view-drupal-7-howto)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom views pager, but the module [Views Simple Pager](http://www.drupal.org/project/views_simple_pager) will do this for you.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.